# how do I install terabyte external WiFi adapter and driver

Tags: drivers

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/FfUuq.jpg)
Please help me I have purchase terabyte  external WiFi dongle and I am new to Ubuntu desktop.so I am not able to install its driver.that has been provided by terabyte

Comment: Does terrabyte provide linux drivers ? What did you try to install drivers ?

Comment: Yes they provide me a CD that has Linux and window driver in sperete folder

Comment: Just I copy and paste to my Ubuntu desktop and extract on desktop

Comment: Please include the output of `lsusb -v`

The most interesting thing is usually the chipset used.

Comment: Lsusb Detail : Bus 001 device 006: I'd 148f:7601 ralink technology,corp.

Comment: Lsusb -v Couldnt open device some information missing

Comment: What is  the Ubuntu version?

Comment: Ubuntu 14.0 lts

Comment: Newer releases (=newer kernels) have better support for MT7601, *I think*, but @Pilot6 may want to correct me about it.